# SQL Oracle, get difference result IN and BETWEEN

Tags: oracle

could someone explain this case?
example, i have a dump table with data like this:

```
TGL
19810909
19761026
19832529
```

when i execute with this query:

```
SELECT to_date(tgl,'YYYYMMDD') tgl
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT tgl  
        FROM tmpx
        WHERE 
        SUBSTR(tgl,5,2) BETWEEN '01' AND '12'
        AND length(tgl) = 8
        )
    WHERE to_date(tgl,'YYYYMMDD') < to_date('19811231','YYYYMMDD')
```

result: no error

```
TGL
09/09/1981
26/10/1976
```

but, when i execute with this query:

```
SELECT to_date(tgl,'YYYYMMDD') tgl
FROM 
    (
    SELECT tgl  
    FROM tmpx
    WHERE 
    SUBSTR(tgl,5,2) IN ('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','01','12')
    AND length(tgl) = 8
    )
WHERE to_date(tgl,'YYYYMMDD') < to_date('19811231','YYYYMMDD')
```

result: error

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

why the row number third (19832529) include in selection that causes an error?
whereas if I execute the following query:

```
SELECT tgl  
FROM tmpx
WHERE 
SUBSTR(tgl,5,2) IN ('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12')
AND length(tgl) = 8
```

the result is like this (wihtout row number 3)

```
TGL
19810909
19761026
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the execution plans for both queries you can see how they are being handled by the optimiser. For the first one:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------                                              
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------                                              
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                              
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TMPX |     1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------                                              

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------                                                                     

   1 - filter(LENGTH("TGL")=8 AND SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)>='01' AND                                                           
              SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)<='12' AND TO_DATE("TGL",'YYYYMMDD')<TO_DATE('                                           
              1981-12-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
```

And for the second:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------                                              
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------                                              
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                              
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TMPX |     1 |     6 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------------                                              

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------                                                                     

   1 - filter(LENGTH("TGL")=8 AND TO_DATE("TGL",'YYYYMMDD')<TO_DATE('                                                   
              1981-12-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND                                                       
              (SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)='01' OR SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)='02' OR                                                      
              SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)='03' OR SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)='04' OR                                                       
              SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)='05' OR SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)='06' OR                                                       
              SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)='07' OR SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)='08' OR                                                       
              SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)='09' OR SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)='10' OR                                                       
              SUBSTR("TGL",5,2)='12'))
```

Notice the order that the filters are applied. In the first one it's looking at the substring first, and only the values that pass that filter will then be converted to a date for the 1998 comparison.

In the second one the date check is being done first, so it tries to convert the invalid value before it filters it out.

The real problem here is storing dates as string, which allows invalid data to be entered. If you're stuck with that then another approach is to use a function to attempt to convert the string to a date and ignore the error(s) thrown, which still isn't ideal but would ignore the same values you already are. There are lots of examples of this, [including this one of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36134502/266304). With something like that you could do:

```
SELECT safe_to_date(tgl) tgl
FROM tmpx
WHERE safe_to_date(tgl) < date '1981-12-31';
```

or if you prefer:

```
SELECT tgl
FROM (
  SELECT safe_to_date(tgl) tgl
  FROM tmpx
)
WHERE tgl < date '1981-12-31';
```

Your function could only look for YYYYMMDD format strings, or you could pass in the format you want to check, if you don't want it to be flexible.

Comment: fyi, datas in dump table are from import txt file. the point is why the third row took executed, which 'where clause' (WHERE to_date(tgl,'YYYYMMDD') < to_date('19811231','YYYYMMDD')) is outside the sub query.

Comment: the sub query should get result 2 rows first

Comment: @thesuhu - but that's up to the optimiser to decide. You could call a `safe_to_date()` type function from SQL\*Loader or an external table definition. Or just use your `between` version, which might break one day if the optimiser chooses differently. But really, if you're getting any invalid data in that field, you have no idea if other data is correct, or wrong but happens to validate.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. i'll try it.

Comment: how to prevent oracle rewrite my query? i used /*+ NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION */ but still not affected.